# scrape linked categories links until no more category

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapy

On this website `https://mavin.io/category` there are multiple categories. Each category then further has more categories and so on. When one category reached last, it shows the product listing like on this page `https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33695`

I want to loop over all of the categories and get the product list link (Not the product links) like this one `https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33695`

What will be the solution to scrape those linked categories?

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = 'https://mavin.io/category'
r = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: have you seen scrapy?

Comment: Yes, I have used it.

Comment: then look for BS4 also and that will parse the webpage for you for links you can then feed into your code above, if you don't want to just set scrapy loose and it it scape all it can find

Comment: any helping article on this?

Comment: best place to start is, as ever, with the original documetnation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Well, there are multiple categories and each category has more categories and one doesn't know how many categories are there. I am struggling to make a solution for this loop so that's why posted it.

Comment: examine the contents of r via BS4. Find the elements in question. Get the pages attached to those elements. Parse again with BS4. Rinse and repeat. Get stuck in with BS4 then you can ask a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a recursive function that traverses all categories until it founds none:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mavin.io/category"
s = requests.session()


def recur(url, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    cat_links = soup.select(".item-image a:has(h4)")
    for a in cat_links:
        yield from recur(
            "https://mavin.io" + a["href"], path + [a.h4.get_text(strip=True)]
        )

    if not cat_links:
        yield r.url, path


for link, path in recur(url):
    print(link, path)
```

Prints:

```
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33695 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Consoles & Parts']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=63691 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Cup Holders']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=40017 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Dash Parts']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33698 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Glove Boxes']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=179848 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Interior Door Handles']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33696 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Interior Door Panels & Parts']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33700 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Pedals & Pads']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33701 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Seats']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=50458 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Seat Belt Shoulder Pads']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33702 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Seat Covers']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33703 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Shift Knobs & Boots']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33704 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Steering Wheels & Horns']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=46102 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Sun Visors']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=50459 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Switches & Controls']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33697 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Floor Mats & Carpets']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=63690 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Cargo Nets, Trays & Liners']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33699 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Mirrors']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33705 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Trim']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=40018 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Window Cranks & Parts']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33706 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Interior', 'Window Motors & Parts']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=33651 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Exterior', 'Racks']
https://mavin.io/search?q=&cat=36475 ['eBay Motors', 'Parts & Accessories', 'Car & Truck Parts', 'Exterior', 'Body Kits']

...and so on.
```